# Am i implementing TTLauncher correctly?

Tags: iphone, three20, ttlauncherview

I was playing around with the TTCatalog example, just tried adding a url with a url mapped in the appdelegate:

```
  [[[TTLauncherItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button 1"
                           image:@"bundle://Icon.png"
                           URL:@"tt://photoTest1" canDelete:YES] autorelease],
```

For some reason, it's not doing anything at all when you click on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you haven't been able to figure this one out yet, my guess is that you are not doing anything in launcherView: didselectitem:

Just create a TTNavigator object inside the method and then call openURLAction. For example

```
(void)launcherView:(TTLauncherView*)launcher didSelectItem:(TTLauncherItem*)item 
{
    TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:item.URL]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If Robert Lowery's answer doesn't work, check your launcher view delegate.

The `TTLauncherView.delegate` property should be pointing to your view controller and should implement the `TTLauncherViewDelegate` protocol. (Otherwise `launcherView:didSelectItem:` will never get called.)